# How to keep an activity running and updating UI while switching to other activities?

Tags: android, sockets, android-activity, android-tabhost, android-lifecycle

Say I have an Activity A which is running a sockets connection to server, the server will keep sending some message and A should process these message and update UI to display them. The sockets connection is running on another thread.

On A I have a button, I wish to press the button and start another activity B.

The requirement is that when user go to activity B, activity A should keep connection with the server and updating its UI. When User back from B, activity A should show up to date info as user never leave.

I did some research, one of the post suggest that using Tabhost Cheat, that put both A and B into an invisible tab host. However I check tab host, when switching tabs the activity will go to onPause state, which disconnect the socket in that activity.

Is solution to work around this? Thank you!

Comment: If you use more than one Activity, then Activity A will always pause. If that disconnects you from the socket, then, you need to do something else that stays within the same activity.

Comment: Why would onPause disconnect a socket? It's your socket. The Activity instance is not destroyed, don't close the socket if you don't want to. Now, a smarter implementation would have the socket survive even if activity A is unloaded after all...

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth taking a look at using an intentservice to do the work with the web socket and have it broadcast messages. In whatever activity you want to read/process the messages you can register a broadcast receiver to get the messages sent from the intentservice thereby ensuring that whenever for example Activity A has it;s onResume method called you could update the ui with the latest messages from the broadcast receiver or just interrogate the intentservice for the latest messages.

The advantage here is that the IntentService will run in the background without needing to any activity hanging around, you might also want to think about introducing something to cut down on the amount  of web traffic by having the intentservice only poll for data when it is needing to be shown thereby reducing battery drain and potential cost to the user with using up data allowances, especially if user is on PAYG

An excellent simple example of how this might work can be found here

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics--mobile-6183